# Parabola, tangent and angles (Apostol, chapter 14.21, problem 1)

Tags: calculus, vectors, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

Apostol, chapter 14.21, problem 1 (a review problem)

Here is the question:

> Let **r** denote the vector from the origin to an arbitrary point on the parabola $y^2 = x$, let $\alpha$ be the angle that **r** makes with the tangent line, $0 \le \alpha \le \pi$, and let $\theta$ be the angle that r makes with the positive x-axis, $0\le \theta\le \pi$. Express $\alpha$ in terms  of $\theta$.

How do I think:
Represent **r** in polar coordinates in function of  $\theta$, the tangent vector will be **r'**. The inner product of **r** and **r'** will give a number, function of $\theta$, which is function of the $\alpha$. But, since $\theta$ is function of t, a parameter inside **r**(t) and **r**'(t), I can't find an expression of r' or r only in function of $\theta$, or to find how to eliminate this parameter. And more, this way to look at the problem doesn't seem good enough.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first thing to do is to find a parametrization of the parabola in terms of the angle $\theta$.  This is quite simple.  If $$(x,y) = (||\boldsymbol r|| \cos \theta, ||\boldsymbol r|| \sin \theta)$$ is the standard polar coordinate transformation, then $y^2 = x$ gives $$||\boldsymbol r||^2 \sin^2 \theta = ||\boldsymbol r|| \cos \theta,$$ where upon solving for $||\boldsymbol r||$ yields $$||\boldsymbol r|| = \csc \theta \cot \theta.$$  This tells us that the desired parametrization is $$\boldsymbol r(\theta) = (x(\theta), y(\theta)) = (\cot^2 \theta, \cot \theta), \quad \theta \in (0,\pi),$$ which in retrospect should be quite obvious.

Once equipped with such a parametrization, it is straightforward to compute the tangent vector $\boldsymbol r'(\theta)$, the dot product $\boldsymbol r \cdot \boldsymbol r'$, and then the angle $\alpha$, which I leave as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

$\theta=\tan^{-1}x$

The angle that the tangent line makes with the positive x axis is $\tan^{-1}2x$

Ergo, $\alpha=\tan^{-1}2x-\tan^{-1}x=\tan^{-1}(2*\tan{\theta})-\theta$